# How to update new array in existing documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following mongo document in collection, now my question i want insert new array in existing documents, i am new to mongodb, kindly any post your code according to my requirement.

```
{
    "schoolID" : "5ca5e1915e6f66641efasr",
    "settings" : {
        "sportsAllowed" : true
    }
},
{
    "schoolID" : "5ca5e1915e6f623466ef3a",
    "settings" : {
        "sportsAllowed" : true
    }
}
```

> Below array need to add my existing documents

```
"Sports": [
               {
               "class": "1",
               "name": "Cricked"
               },
              { 
                "class": "2",
               "type": "Football"
              }
        ]
```

> Expected output

```
{
    "schoolID" : "5ca5e1915e6f66641efasr",
    "settings" : {
        "sportsAllowed" : true,
        "Sports": [
               {
               "class": "1",
               "name": "Cricked"
               },
              { 
                "class": "2",
               "type": "Football"
              }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "schoolID" : "5ca5e1915e6f623466ef3a",
    "settings" : {
        "sportsAllowed" : true,
        "Sports": [
               {
               "class": "1",
               "name": "Cricked"
               },
              { 
                "class": "2",
               "type": "Football"
              }
        ]
    }
}
```

> My Code

```
var value=[
    {
        "class": "1",
        "name": "Cricked"
    },
    { 
        "class": "2",
        "type": "Football"
    }
]

db.Colleges.update({},{
    $set : {
        "Sports": value
    }
},{multi:true})
```

Comment: Please provide the code snippet of your schema

Comment: @Avik, i have posted my code, kindly check

Answer (score 0):

You can use update without any matching condition, and `multi:true` to update all the documents in your collection.

Try this :

```
var value=[
    {
        "class": "1",
        "name": "Cricked"
    },
    { 
        "class": "2",
        "type": "Football"
    }
]

db.collection_name.update({},{
    $set : {
        "Sports": value
    }
},{multi:true})
```

Comment: I used your code but not getting my expected output

Comment: It is creating separate `Sports` array but i need to create inside `settings`

Answer (score 0):

```
let updateWith = {
    'settings.Sports': [
        {
            "class": "1",
            "name": "Cricked"
        },
        {
            "class": "2",
            "type": "Football"
        }
    ]
}
let updateWhere = {}
collection_name.update(updateWhere, { $set: updateWith }, { multi: true }, function (err, affected) {
})
OR..................
let updateWith = [
    {
        "class": "1",
        "name": "Cricked"
    },
    {
        "class": "2",
        "type": "Football"
    }
]
collection_name.update(updateWhere, { $set: { 'settings.Sports': updateWith } }, { multi: true }, function (err, affected) {
})
```